# Convert key value pairs in column into JSON syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a PostgreSQL table containing a column with key value pairs ("KeyValuePairs" of text) separated by a semicolon character:

| Id | Name | KeyValuePairs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Key1:Value1;Key2:Value2;Key3:Value3 |
| 2 | B | Key10:Value10;Key11:Value11 |
| 3 | C | Key20:Value20;Key21:Value21;Key22:Value22;Key23:Value23;Key24:Value24 |

How do i convert the text of KeyValuePairs into a JSON syntax (still of type text, not JSON) using a SQL query?
The expected result is:

| Id | Name | KeyValuePairs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | { "Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "Key3": "Value3" } |
| 2 | B | { "Key10": "Value10", "Key11": "Value11" |
| 3 | C | etc. |

#### Update: Solution

Using the solution from Serg i was able to solve it, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9c151/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `replace` the delimiters

```
select Id,Name, '{"' || replace(replace(KeyValuePairs, ':', '":"'),';','","')  || '"}' KeyValuePairs
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Json Object and parse that string into json

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
```

You might want to refer to Json.NET [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

Comment: I think user819068 wants a SQL solution